# Why is 'pitest-maven' build project on Jenkins server not loading the "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" class?

Tags: java, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, junit5, pitest

While creating mutation tests on a pitest-maven integrated project this error is popping, I assume it's not creating logs in the project using 'Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)'.
 I need to know, Why is the mentioned below class not loading??
 any possible logical reasoning would help me to get an Idea.
Thanks

And Yes, I have Checked pom.xml file and related dependencies required for the project..

I have checked the log4j2.xml file..

```
// below is the XML content in my log4j2.xml..
    // I cannot find log4j.properties in project resources I Am using IntelliJ on mac.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- <configuration status="OFF"> -->
    <configuration status="DEBUG"> 
        <appenders>
            <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
            </Console>
        </appenders>
        <loggers>
            <Logger name="rockets" level="trace" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            </Logger>
            <Root level="error">
                <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
            </Root>
        </loggers>

         <Appenders>
           <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT"/>  
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/> 
         <Socket name="LF5_SOCKET" host="localhost" port="4454" protocol="TCP" reconnectionDelay="5000"/>  
     </Appenders> 
        <Loggers>
     <Logger name="rockets" level="info" additivity="false"> 
<AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
</Logger>  
        <Root level="trace">  
              <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="DEBUG"/>   
             <AppenderRef ref="LF5_SOCKET" level="DEBUG"/>   
        </Root>  
    </Loggers>
    </configuration>
```

> console log

```
// below  is the error log from the Jenkins server console


/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\12:24:20 PM PIT >> INFO : MINION : SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

|/-\|/-\|/12:24:21 PM PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 2 seconds.
12:24:21 PM PIT >> INFO : Created  7 mutation test units
stderr  : SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
/stderr  : SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
-\|/stderr  : SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
-\12:24:30 PM PIT >> INFO : Completed in 11 seconds
================================================================================
```

I need to know, How do I make SLF4J Load the class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you provide a minimum working example, we may be able to help you.

Comment: I added My log4j2.xml file I can't find log4j.properties file in my project if that helps ?

Comment: Maybe you have only a log4j2.xml in main/resources and none (log4j2-test.xml) in test/resources?